# Custom label circle at specific degree intervals

Tags: tikz-pgf, circles

In order to draw a circle with numeric labels at specific degree intervals, I use the following code.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=rect,line width=3pt]
\draw[] (0,0) circle [radius=8cm];
\foreach \angle [count=\xi] in {60,30,...,-270}
{
  \draw[line width=1.5pt] (\angle:7.8cm) -- (\angle:8.2cm);
  \node[font=\large] at (\angle:9cm) {\xi*12000};
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The labels should constitute products of the loop counter and the integer 12000 and shall, consequently, read 12000, 24000, 36000, etc. The current code, however, prints the multiplication literally as a string.

What would correct code look like?

Comment: It will overflow with dimension too large. You need to process it with fpu library.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two other ways without loading any extra package. Note that I did `\xi*12` and added the `000` manually to ease and speed up the calculation and thus the compiling process.

### With a `\pgfmathtruncatemacro`

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=rect,line width=3pt]
\draw[] (0,0) circle [radius=8cm];
\foreach \angle [count=\xi] in {60,30,...,-270}{
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\xx}{\xi*12}
  \draw[line width=1.5pt] (\angle:7.8cm) -- (\angle:8.2cm);
  \node[font=\large] at (\angle:9cm) {\xx 000};
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Using the in-built functionality `evaluate`

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=rect,line width=3pt]
\draw[] (0,0) circle [radius=8cm];
\foreach \angle [count=\xi, evaluate=\xi as \xx using int(\xi*12)] in {60,30,...,-270}{
  \draw[line width=1.5pt] (\angle:7.8cm) -- (\angle:8.2cm);
  \node[font=\large] at (\angle:9cm) {\xx 000};
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And here's the result in both cases:

[image]

Comment: Your solution using the in-built functionality `evaluate` works perfectly and, in addition, is both succinct and easily readable. Hence, I selected it as the preferred method.

Answer (score 2):

The [`fp`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/fp) package has what you need - try the code below.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,fp}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=rect,line width=3pt]
\draw[] (0,0) circle [radius=8cm];
\foreach \angle [count=\xi] in {60,30,...,-270}
{
  \FPeval{\result}{round(\xi*12000,0)}
  \draw[line width=1.5pt] (\angle:7.8cm) -- (\angle:8.2cm);
  \node[font=\large] at (\angle:9cm) {\result};
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

A way to do this with MetaPost (coding included in a LuaLaTeX program for typesetting convenience).

It makes use of the `freelabel` macro for circular labelling, which is provided by the Metafun format of MetaPost, and of the `numprint` LaTeX package for number formatting.

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib, numprint}
  \mplibtextextlabel{enable}
  \mplibsetformat{metafun}
  \mplibnumbersystem{double}
\begin{document}
  \begin{mplibcode}
    beginfig(0);
      u = 3cm; len = 4bp; pair radius, hmark;
      draw fullcircle scaled 2u;
      freelabeloffset := 6bp;
      for i = 1 upto 12:
        angl := 90-30i;
        radius := u*dir angl; hmark := .5len*dir angl;
        draw (-hmark -- hmark) shifted radius;
        freelabel("\numprint{" & decimal(12000i) & "}", radius, origin);
      endfor;
    endfig;
  \end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

[image]